# Simple skeleton for AngularJS without dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, bower

I am trying to get an AngularJS skeleton for setting my project, but it seems that every skeleton available online requires the installation of a ton of dependencies via npm and/or bower.

I am trying to avoid downloading via nmp due to the fact that the project is for a firm and there are security complications. My idea was to get the dependencies manually, but they seem to be countless. Could anyone suggest me an alternative or propose a solution?

These are the sort of dependencies npm installs:

```
"dependencies": {
"angular": "1.2.6",
"angular-cookies": "1.2.6",
"angular-resource": "1.2.6",
"angular-route": "1.2.6",
"angular-sanitize": "1.2.6",
"angular-http-auth": "1.2.1",
"async": "~0.2.5",
"bootstrap": "~3.0.3",
"angular-ui-bootstrap": "~0.10.0",
"es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
"jquery": "~1.10.2",
"json3": "~3.2.4",
"requirejs": "~2.1.9",
"underscore": "~1.5.2",
"pace": "~0.5.5",
"fontawesome-actions": "~0.5.0",
"ui-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
"angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
"selectn": "~0.9.6",
"select2": "~3.4.8",
"angular-ui-select2": "~0.0.5",
"angular-ui": "~0.4.0",
"inflection": "~1.3.8",
"momentjs": "~2.8.1",
"jquery-minicolors": "~2.1.6"


 },


"devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.6",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.6",
    "sinon": "~1.7.3",
    "chai": "~1.8.1"
  },
```

Comment: How about using a cdn to load the scripts? Then you don't need an installation. Or you could download the required dependencies and bundle them in one minified js file. If you would use [`jspm`](http://jspm.io/) instead of bower for front-end dependencies you could easily use the built-in bundling function.

Answer (score 2):

You could use bower to install only what you want.

Start creating a bower.json file and you could start with only certain packages:

```
{
  "name": "Your_app_name",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "latest",
    "font-awesome": "latest",
    "animate.css": "latest",
    "angular": "latest",
    "angular-route": "latest",
    "angular-cookies": "latest",
    "angular-resource": "latest"
  }
}
```

Then run :

```
$> bower install
```

And add only what you need.
I made a basic template that I use when I start a new project : https://github.com/etienne-bondot/angular-template